# Issues in pointer to char* value

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

What is the issue with this code (It is printing arr[0] correctly but I am getting issues with arr[1]... printing some weird characters):

```
using namespace std;
char ** setName() {
    char * arr[2];
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
       arr[i] = (char*)malloc(100);
    arr[0] = strdup("Robert");
    arr[1] = strdup("Jose");
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    char **arr;
    arr = setName();
    printf("First name is %s\n", arr[0]);
    printf("Second name is %s\n", arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

If it matters, i am running this code in Windows using Visual Studio 8.

Comment: you dont need the malloc, as strdup allocates anyway

Comment: Why in the world are you mixing `malloc` and `printf` with C++ code that uses the `std` namespace? Pick a language and stick with it: either C or C++.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>`, and you'll be much happier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems in that code:

1. An `auto` array such as your `char * arr[2]` is not automatically created with `new[]`; its storage goes away when the function returns.  This is the source of your garbage.  You should `malloc()` or `new[]` it.

   ```
   char **arr = malloc(2 * sizeof (*char));
   ```
2. `strdup()` does a `malloc()`, so you are pointlessly `malloc()`ing storage that is then lost because you overwrite the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the address of a local variable. `arr` doesn't exist after `setName` exits, so `main`'s `arr` is pointing to bad memory.

You'd be better off writing straight into `main`'s `arr` by passing it as a parameter to `setName`:

```
using namespace std;
void setName(char* (&arr)[2]) {
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
       arr[i] = (char*)malloc(100);
    arr[0] = strdup("Robert");
    arr[1] = strdup("Jose");
}
int main()
{
    char * arr[2];
    setName(arr);
    printf("First name is %s\n", arr[0]);
    printf("Second name is %s\n", arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array of pointers is local to your setName function.

Try something like:

```
char ** setName() {
  char ** arr = (char **)malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
  for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    arr[i] = (char*)malloc(100);
  strcpy(arr[0], "Robert");
  strcpy(arr[1], "Jose");
  return arr;
}
```

... and don't forget to `free` what you `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the address of arr.  This is undefined behavior and you really don't know what's going to happen.  I would strongly suggest you add a parameter to that function by reference and just pass arr to it from main instead of returning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be something like this:

```
    char *setName() {
        char * arr[2];
        static int j=0;
        int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
            arr[i] = (char*)malloc(100);
        strcpy(arr[0],"Robert");
        strcpy(arr[1],"Jose");
        return arr[j++];
    }

    int main(){
        char *arr1,*arr2;
        arr1 = setName();
        arr2 = setName();   
        printf("First name is %s\n", arr1);
        printf("First name is %s\n", arr2);
        return 0;
    }
```